# $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f^n(a)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(z-a)^n$  such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f^n(a)$ converges then is it necessary that $f(z) $ is entire.
I have tried this by giving counter example but all in vain , Any hints leading to answer are deeply  appreciated

Comment: My guess is that you meant $f^{(n)}$, instead of $f^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_n(z-a)^{n}$ in some neighborhood of $a$ then $a_n =\frac {f^{(n)} (a)} {n!}$. Since $f^{(n) }(a)\to 0$ it follows (by comparison with exponential series)  that the series converges for all $z$ and $f$ extends to an entire function.

Comment: How did you get $ a_n =\frac {f^{(n)} (a)} {n!}$

Comment: and how did you expand it for all $z$

Comment: That comes from a basic theorem about power series. Any book on Complex Analysis contains a proof.

Comment: The series $\sum \frac {f^{(n)}(a)} {n!}(z-a)^{n}$ converges for all $z$ because $f^{(n)}(a)$ is  a bounded sequence. But this is same as the original series so the original series converges for all $z$.